# R: Fastest way to do row wise computation on multiple columns of a data frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame where I want to add another column that's a result of computation involving 3 other columns. The method I am using right now seems to be very slow. Is there any better method to do the same. Here is the approach I am using.

```
library(bitops)

GetRes<-function(A, B, C){
  tagU <- bitShiftR((A*C), 4)
  tagV <- bitShiftR(B, 2)

  x<-tagU %% 2
  y<-tagV %% 4

  res<-(2*x + y) %% 4
  return(res)
}

df <- data.frame(id=letters[1:3],val0=1:3,val1=4:6,val2=7:9)
apply(df, 1, function(x) GetRes(x[2], x[3], x[4]))
```

My data frame is very big and it's taking ages to get this computation done. Can someone suggest me to do it better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you're doing is already vectorized which is much faster than any other alternative you'll be offered.  You can just call this...

```
with(df, GetRes(val0, val1, val2))
```

or this

```
GetRes(df$val0, df$val1, df$val2)
```

or this

```
GetRes(df[,2], df[,3], df[,4])
```

Answer (score 7):

Try `mapply`

```
mapply(GetRes, df[,2], df[,3], df[,4])
```

If you let us know which package `bitShiftR`  is from, we can test it on bigger data to see if there is any performance boost.

**UPDATE**
Quick benchmarking shows, `mapply` is twice as fast as your `apply`

```
microbenchmark(apply(df[,2:4], 1, function(x) GetRes(x[1], x[2], x[3])), mapply(GetRes, df[,2], df[,3], df[,4]))
Unit: microseconds
                                                      expr     min       lq   median      uq      max neval
 apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) GetRes(x[1], x[2], x[3])) 196.985 201.6200 206.7515 216.187 1006.775   100
                 mapply(GetRes, df[, 2], df[, 3], df[, 4])  99.982 105.6105 108.7560 112.232  149.311   100
```

Comment: Added. it is from `bitops`

Comment: And if `mapply`works faster, it might be also worth to use the parallel version of it: `library(parallel) ; mcapply(GetRes, df[,2], df[,3], df[,4], mc.cores=xxx)`, where `xxx`is the amount of cores in your computer.